# Slanted diagonal line in html or css?

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I want to make a Table like this
[image: CSS diagonale strike]

is it possible to add a **slanted diagonal border** in table?

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nsrbL0d1/) with linear-gradients in background. Gradients are not supported in IE 9 and lower though. But angled gradients tend to produce jagged lines. (Note: Demo works only on Chrome).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Based on [CSS3 linear-gradients](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#linear-gradients) solution except that the angle is not hard coded:

```css
table:nth-of-type(1) td {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to top right,
    white 48%,
    black,
    white 52%
  );
}
table:nth-of-type(2) td {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to top right,
    papayawhip calc(50% - 1px),
    black,
    papayawhip calc(50% + 1px)
  );
}
/* for testing */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
td:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 10em;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
  width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Narrow</td>
      <td>Wide</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Narrow</td>
      <td>Wide</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Narrow</td>
      <td>Wide</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Narrow</td>
      <td>Wide</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice option. Do you know of a way to make it work in older versions of Chrome?

Comment: @Harry: use vendor prefixes (`-webkit-gradient`, `-webkit-linear-gradient` etc) for somewhat older browsers. But I am not sure if left and top keywords are supported.

Comment: @SalmanA: True but they don't seem to support the `to top right` option and general `top right` or angles don't seem to be dynamic. Anyways, I think this is the best that can be done. Cheers :)

Comment: You need to enable "print background images" setting in your browser settings/print dialog.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach would be to use **SVG** as it can scale easily to the size of your container.

**Example :**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.l{width:200px;}
.xl{width:300px;}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="s">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="l">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="xl">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, nice and simple! Just be sure to type `viewBox` (camelCased), and not `viewbox` for your svgs. The latter will not work for dynamic content (inserted by Angular and probably other front end frameworks). Tripped me up! https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8987

Comment: @evilkos well spotted, thanks. I corrected the typo ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could produce this slanted inner border effect using either one of the below methods but both needs the angles (skew/gradient) to be adjusted based on the height and width of your table cell.

> Note: This might not be the best option (and I can't think of any other better options either) when the cell dimensions are dynamic/auto as the angles would need modification.

**Option 1:** Using Skew Transform on a pseudo-element

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  display: inline-block; /* doesn't seem to work in FF without this */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px; /* for vertical centering */
}
td:after {
  position:absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(63deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(63deg);
  transform: skewX(63deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Option 2:** Using Linear Gradients in Background (Not supported by IE9 and lower)

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
    <td>
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i get a lot of new ideas with your answer. And your worth for +1.. But I got my answer from salman A..

Comment: @DatzMe: Always glad to help mate and Salman's answer is definitely the better one :)

Comment: yeah that's why I choose his answer but u did a great job to help the beginner like us.. Thank you so much

Comment: how to display `gradient` when i print the page?

Comment: @DatzMe: I hope you have got the answer from Salman's comments.

Answer (score 3):

In case this is useful, I created a plain HTML + CSS solution for this which only needs small customization of the cells height and colors:

https://codepen.io/davoscript/pen/GdWMwV

```css
.equilibrium{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: #8bc34a;
}

.equilibrium td{
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.equilibrium td{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.equilibrium .sup{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.equilibrium .inf{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 15%;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.equilibrium td::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<table class="equilibrium" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="sup">1</span>
        <span class="inf">2</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="sup">1</span>
        <span class="inf">2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="sup">1</span>
        <span class="inf">2</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="sup">1</span>
        <span class="inf">2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Nice solution, very elegant! Only that I changed colors and esp. `clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);` to draw diagonal from top-left to right-bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply specify a diagonal line by defining a linear gradient.

```css
table td{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/* This will  be hidden, just to make the real line straight instead of dotted line */
td.diagonalCross{
     position:   relative;
     background:  linear-gradient(to right top, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 49.9%,#000000 50%,#000000 51%,#ffffff 51.1%,#ffffff 100%) !important;
     background-color: transparent;
     background-image: none !important;
}

/* The real diagonal line */
td.diagonalCross:after{
     content:     "";
     display:     block;
     position:    absolute;
     width:       100%;
     height:      100%;
     top:         0;
     left:        0;
     z-index:     -1;
     /* Rising diagonal line */
     background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, white, white 48%, black 49%, black 51%, white 52%, white) !important;
     /* Falling diagonal line */
     background: linear-gradient(to right top, white, white 48%, black 49%, black 51%, white 52%, white) !important;  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Naveno</td>
    <td>ID-123</td>
    <td class="diagonalCross"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ho</td>
    <td >ID-223</td>
    <td class="diagonalCross"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lee</td>
    <td >ID-221</td>
    <td class="diagonalCross"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Min</td>
    <td >ID-231</td>
    <td class="diagonalCross"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS Fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/navenoc13/t6w93nzp/9/).

Answer (score 0):

you can add the transform-origin property and changed the translate value

```
div.line
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -61px;
    width: 423px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Check the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/LWAKn/123/

*let me know if u are looking for something else*

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a table border same as the example in the image. I want that slashing border inside the table cell.

Comment: @DatzMe ok , did a lot of work and updated my answer , check it out now

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using js & css. Please check the code below.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
<div id="myTextArea"></div>    
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.moveTo(0,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,0);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
</script>

<style>
html, body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#myCanvas {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#myTextArea {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  height: 102px;
  width: 202px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>


`
```