# Diagonal line in HTML Table - email signature

Tags: css, html-email

I need to have a table layout in my HTML signature, but need diagonal lines. I know that this requires inline CSS, but is there an option to use pseudo elements inline?

I have this example for diagonal lines in a table - but not sure how to incorporate that into an HTML email signature.

Any thoughts?

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #FFF;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  position: relative;
}

/* Very top border */
table:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 240px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: none;
}

/* Far right headers top border (it's outside the table) */
table:after { 
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  width: 101px;
  right: -101px;
  top: 0;
}

/* 
 - Apply header background/font colour 
 - Set base z-index for IE 9 - 10
*/
thead, th:before {
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* min-width and max-width together act like a width */
th {
 min-width: 60px;
 max-width: 60px;
 position: relative;
 height: 100px;
}

/* Pseudo element borders */
th:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -50px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 60px;
 border: solid 1px #000;
 border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
 transform: skew(-45deg);
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Apply the right border only to the last pseudo element */
thead th:last-child:before {
 border-right: solid 1px #000;
}

/* Apply the top border only to the first rows cells */
tbody tr:first-child td {
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
}

/* 
 - Rotate and position headings
 - Padding centers the text vertically and does the job of height
 - z-index ensures that the text appears over the background color in IE 9 - 10
*/
th span {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  right: -70px;
  bottom: 29px;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0.75em 0 1.85em;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Create first two th styles */
th:nth-child(1),th:nth-child(2)  {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
th:nth-child(2) {
 border-right: none;
}
th:nth-child(1):before,
th:nth-child(2):before  {
 display: none; 
}

td {
 border: solid 1px #000;
 border-bottom: none;
 border-top: none;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

tfoot { 
 border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>One</th>
     <th>Two</th>
              <th><span>Three</span></th>
     <th><span>Four</span></th>
              <th><span>Five</span></th>
              <th><span>Six</span></th>
              <th><span>Seven</span></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
   </tr>
   
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inline pseudos won't be possible as Quentin has already mentioned in his answer. You could have a look at some background gradients like mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425574/slanted-diagonal-line-in-html-or-css/28425841#28425841)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there an option to use pseudo elements inline

No. Inline style attributes can apply CSS to a given element. They replace selectors entirely.