# How to create a crooked line inside td of a table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table that i want to separate data in td tag with a crooked line Like this :
[image: Sample table picture]

How can i do it with css?

Data in table fill dynamically So the width of td is not fixed,it depends on length of data in it.

Comment: Just FYI all you need to change in the duplicate question's answer is `to top right` to `to top left`.

Comment: Seems like already have been asked in SO, Pls refer below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425574/slanted-diagonal-line-in-html-or-css

Comment: @rory-mccrossan Thank you, i didn't know exactly how to search that question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure CSS example, using `after` and `transform: rotate`:

```css
.diagonal{border:1px solid gray;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
 }

.diagonal:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    border-top:1px solid red;
    width:150%;
    left:100%;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    top:0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class='diagonal'></td>  
   </tr>
</table>
```